# Python global variable not updating inside definition

Tags: python, numpy

I'm relatively new to Python programming. I've run into a problem where a variable that I have defined as global isn't updating inside a definition. I (despite my best effort) can't wrap my head around what could be wrong.

Here is the code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
arraySize = 10
arrayPrecision = 0.1
array = []
x = 0
f_x = x

def arrayMaker():
   global x
   global f_x
   for n in np.arange(-arraySize/2, 0, arrayPrecision):
       x = n
       array.append(f_x)
   for n in np.arange(0, (arraySize/2)+0.1, arrayPrecision):
       x = n
       array.append(f_x)
   print(array)

arrayMaker()
```

When I run this code, it prints an array filled with zeroes, and the expression f_x returns 0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You never modify f_x, so why should it be anything other than 0?

Comment: If I've declared f_x as equal to x, shouldn't f_x update alongside x?

Comment: They start off pointing at the same value. But then you *reassign* `x` to something else, leaving `f_x` pointing at the original value.

Comment: How would i then have something like f_x = 3*x+4, without having to manually enter it into each loop? The idea is that f_x will change with each run of the program.

Comment: From the comments it looks like you think `f_x` is somehow a pointer to `x` but this is not true in python or as written in any programming language that I am aware of. `a = 1; b=2; a=b; b=3; # what is a??`

Comment: Step back a bit.  You shouldn't be using globals, especially with your level of understanding.  Pass the variables as arguments, and return the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it looks like you misunderstand a few things, but here is what it looks like you are looking for. Essentially you are looking for late evaluation of `f_x`. From the name `f_x` is actually a function, so you should define it like a function. Here is your code adjusted.

```
import math
import numpy as np
arraySize = 10
arrayPrecision = 0.1
array = []
x = 0
f_x = lambda x: 3*x+4

def arrayMaker():
   for n in np.arange(-arraySize/2, 0, arrayPrecision):
       x = n
       array.append(f_x(x))
   for n in np.arange(0, (arraySize/2)+0.1, arrayPrecision):
       x = n
       array.append(f_x(x))
   print(array)

arrayMaker()
```